Why is the type {} inferred instead of unknown when strictNullChecks is disabled?
Consider the following code:
const { name } = "something" as unknown;

When I enable Typescript's strictNullChecks, I get the following error message:
Error: Property `name` does not exist on type `unknown`

Which sounds about right.
But when I disable strictNullChecks, I get the following error message:
Error: Property `name` does not exist on type `{}`

What does {} mean here?
I only know {} as non-nullish value. But why is it inferred here instead of unknown?

I'ld say: you're accessing the property of an object which cannot null/undefined (b/'c you rule these possibilities out with disabling strictNullChecks). So TypeScriipt assumes it's an object of unknown properties. That said, I don't understand where results is coming from - it doesn't appear in you code line.

@NotX {} stands for non-nullish value in Typescript -- so it could also be number. Thank you for pointing out the mistake in the error message -- I fixed it.

But you couldn't access name of a number or the alike.


What does {} mean here? I only know {} as non-nullish value. But why is it inferred here instead of unknown?

When strictNullChecks is false, null and undefined might as well not exist; they're ignored by the language. As you said {} means a non-nullish value, and if null and undefined don't exist, that's everything. So when strictNullChecks are turned off, {} and unknown are equivalent.
